# Method of cooling a gas without liquid evaporation for Sci-fi novel

Tags: gas-laws, temperature

sorry for the amateur question here.

I know little about science, but regardless am writing a fictional amateur novel that deals with a lot of chemistry stuff, especially gasses.

My protagonist needs a clever method of cooling a gas.  He has access to several gasses (CO2, O2, H2, nitrogen) in varying temperatures (70c and up).  Unfortunately no water (at least not more than a few bottles).  The atmosphere he is working under (planet atmosphere) is in the range of 150c and at a pressure of roughly 150kpa in the novel.

He also has access to sci-fi style manufacturing machines that can simply 'make' parts, like pipes, valves, pumps, that sort of thing.

I am looking for a clever way or really any way at all, that he can use to cool down some O2 to at least under 40c in such a situation.

My amateur reading online suggests the main way, is via liquid evaporation, but I doubt that would work in the above scenario easily.

Does anybody have any ideas?  Is this even possible?

Comment: Let the gas expand into a larger container then the one that is currently holding it. You can calculate that change by using a simple algebraic relationship called Charles law, where (V1T1)/V2=T2 where V1 and T1 are the initial volumes and temp while V2 is the final volume.

Comment: Thermal pumps? The same principle as  a fridge or climatization.

Comment: @Poutnik definitely more clever and interesting then expansion...

Comment: @Poutnik They use some liquid - the point of question is its lack. Or wait, "few bottles" is a lot, so maybe it would work.

Comment: @Mithoron It was not clear if any liquid, even in a closed cycles, or one time open evaporation.  // Another option is thermoelectric [Peltier effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoelectric_effect#Peltier_effect). Not very effective, but principally suitable.

Comment: Just put it on ice

Comment: Unfortunately thermoelectric cooling is out.  It would need dedicated device/hardware and I'm keeping that under the 'he doesn't have the right materials to construct) category of things.  Evaporation I looked into and seems too impractical.  As for expansion I actually thought of something like that, but I don't really understand that in terms of the ideal gas law.  If the gas gained access to more volume, wouldn't that just decrease the pressure and not the temperature?  I don't really understand it too well. @dval98

Comment: Another option is [Joule-thompson effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule%E2%80%93Thomson_effect) based cyclical expansion / compression machine, usually used for liquifying gases, this time would be used just for gas cooling.

Comment: @Poutnik Trying to understand the Joule-thompson cyclical thing, as that seems to be what I'm after.  If I have a closed loop, maintaining a high pressure in area A and and a low pressure in area B, using at least two pumps (pumping to keep the low pressure flow going and then back into the high pressure area), would that cause area A to be hotter and area B to be cooler?  Or am I being way too naïve here?

Comment: @user2765977 - There are several good suggestions here, and I'll make one that really adds nothing but is pretty neat and you could probably get away with including it given artistic license: check out [pressure swing adsorption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure_swing_adsorption), which is used commercially to separate gas components from air.

Comment: @user2765977 A gas is being compressed, warms up by compression and is let  to cool down back to the surrounding temperature. Then it is being expanded through throttling ventil to low pressure (kept by a pump ) what cools it down. A part of cold gas leaves the system for the final usage (or is used as an input for the next unit in case of multi unit system. ), being replaced by input of warmer gas.

Comment: Thank you.  I actually already had a friend explain to me what you just commented (he works with 'heat exchange' stuff).  So when the timer is up, will post a variation of that as the answer I'm using and will credit you.

Answer (score 1):

Poutnik's answers led to the result I desired, his explanation was just a bit too technical for a layman like me.  Basically I will use gas expansion for the cooling, that is where the gas is doing the work.

A closed loop, force pumps gas into a high pressure area (low volume) and then uses a sort of valve to let the gas expand into the high volume area.  the pump (intake) and valve (outtake) work in tandem to keep the expansion flow going and causes cooling.

Thanks to all that helped.

Comment: This is SCIENCE FICTION you have an opportunity to invent a completely impossible method to cool something that violates all the Laws of Thermodynamics In such a convoluted manner that you probably could apply for a patent on it and you are asking us for help to make it rigorous? Shame!